# Copy documents in another index on creation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We want to keep track of all the changes of a document, so we want to store all the document versions in separate index.

Is there a way when a new document is added or changes to send the entire document in another index? Maybe there is a processor for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Elasticsearch as such supports only version numbers but there is no way to trace back to previous version.

You could maintain version history in a seperate elastic index

Whenever you update main_index ensure that you update main_index as well

```
POST main_index/_doc/doc_id
POST main_index/_doc/doc_id_version
```

May be you can configure logstash to do this...not sure

Comment: Yes, this is the intention, and we are looking for some tool from Elasticsearch to implement this, as in case of sending 2 requests the second request can fail and we should handle this